# Background image not appearing

Tags: html, css

The background image in the shadow_div is not appearing as it is expected to be .
Although rest of the images are loading and appearing properly which are in mySlider div
but what  about the background-image of the shadow_div?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>jQuery UI Dialog: Hide the Close Button/Title Bar</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {


    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">

    .mySlider
    {
        width:800px;
        height:480px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:10px auto;
    }

    .shadow_div
    {
        background-image:url(Images\shadow.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:top;
        width:510px;
        height:296px;
        margin:-90px auto;

    }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="my_image_slider" class="mySlider">
        <img src="Images\audi.jpg" alt="" title="Audi India"/>
        <img src="Images\bmw.jpg" alt="" title="BMW India" />
        <img src="Images\aston-martin.jpg" alt="" title="Aston-Martin APAC" />
        <img src="Images\bugatti.jpg" alt="" title="Buggatti APAC" />
        <img src="Images\koenigsegg.jpg" alt="" title="Koenigsegg APAC" />
</div><br />
<div class="shadow_div" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using **Backslash** `\` symbol.

```
<img src="Images\audi.jpg" alt="" title="Audi India"/>
```

you should use **Forward Slash** `/` Symbol . also make sure image path is right.

```
<img src="Images/audi.jpg" alt="" title="Audi India"/>
```

Here you can see the image in class `.shadow_div` is appearing. See the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/citibipi/1/edit)**.

Comment: But that pictures are loading in the div with the class .mySlider
only the background-image in the div .shadow_div is not loading :(
I tried your way too
but it is not loading

Comment: I've share a demo link also, please see the image is appearing in the class `.shadow_div`. http://jsbin.com/citibipi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not getting correct path: try this below, as you are using forward slash **'\'**
instead of backslash '**/'**

```
    <img src="Images/audi.jpg" alt="" title="Audi India"/>
    <img src="Image/bmw.jpg" alt="" title="BMW India" />
    <img src="Image/aston-martin.jpg" alt="" title="Aston-Martin APAC" />
    <img src="Image/bugatti.jpg" alt="" title="Buggatti APAC" />
    <img src="Image/koenigsegg.jpg" alt="" title="Koenigsegg APAC" />
```